# Atom text editor not setting background image

Tags: css, sass, atom-editor

I'm trying to set background for my atom text editor from the post 
https://discuss.atom.io/t/setting-background-images/9002

I tried the same code and I'm not sure why the editor is not rendering any background image. Can someone please help?

I'm attaching the stylesheet. Styles for setting background is in the last 7 lines of the snippet.

```css
/*
 * Code by William Chang and Matt McFarland
 * https://medium.com/@docodemore/an-alternative-to-operator-mono-font-6e5d040e1c7e#.ofkdp0aww
 * flottflott - http://www.dafont.com/flottflott.font
 * Fira Code - https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode
*/

atom-text-editor {
    font-family: 'Fira Code';
    font-style: normal;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

atom-text-editor.editor {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    .syntax--string.syntax--quoted,
    .syntax--string.syntax--regexp {
        -webkit-font-feature-settings: "liga" off, "calt" off;
    }

    .syntax--source.syntax--js.syntax--jsx > .syntax--keyword.syntax--control.syntax--flow.syntax--js,
    .syntax--storage,
    .syntax--type .syntax--function {
        vertical-align: baseline;
        font-family: 'flottflott';
        height: inherit;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        line-height: 1rem;
    }

    .syntax--storage.syntax--type.syntax--function.syntax--arrow.syntax--js {
        font-size: 1.5em;
        line-height: 1rem;
    }

    .syntax--comment {
        font-style: italic;
    }

    .syntax--source.syntax--js.syntax--jsx > .syntax--keyword.syntax--control.syntax--flow.syntax--js {
        font-family: 'Fira Code';
        font-style: normal;
    }

    .syntax--string.syntax--unquoted.syntax--js {
        color: #CDD3DE;
    }

    .syntax--entity.syntax--name {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
}
.pane {
    background: url('http://gzhaixier.com/data/out/62/46169594-dark-background-images.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}
.editor {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I tried viewing the image in my browser and it gets a redirect to http://gzhaixier.com/dark-background-images.html. Have you verified that URL?

Comment: Im able to view the background image @Greg

Comment: http://prntscr.com/euqgqt

Comment: what if you use `background-image: url("");`

Comment: Mike, that didnt work too. Although, I downloded the image and used background-image and it works fine. Thank you very much!